# How to upgrade PowerShell?

Tags: windows, powershell, upgrade

I installed the PowerShell, and now I see a message when lauching it

> A new PowerShell stable release is available: v7.2.5
> Upgrade now, or check out the release page at:
> https://aka.ms/PowerShell-Release?tag=v7.2.5

[image]

How to upgrade PowerShell?

I read from [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/install/installing-powershell-on-windows?view=powershell-7.2#upgrading-an-existing-installation)

> For best results when upgrading, you should use the same install
> method you used when you first installed PowerShell.

What does mean "best results when upgrading"? There are *worst* results and sometimes *best* ones?

Is there a command line upgrade utility?

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/install/installing-powershell-on-windows?view=powershell-7.2

Comment: https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell scroll down a bit

Comment: @Gantendo I don't see the way to upgrade in articles you sent the link and I already saw it

Comment: PowerShell 7.x is the cross-platform version, so some modules were lost. I recommend staying with version 5.x, as it's better integrated with Windows.

Comment: I don’t understand your question. Why don’t you just download the current version and install it?

Comment: How hard exactly is it for you to download the MSI installer and install PowerShell? And the line you quoted made absolutely no sense at all.

Comment: @ΞένηΓήινος I didn't say it's hard, I asked if there is a command line upgrade mode

Comment: The "Upgrade now" message is misleading; I always think there is a built-in method to upgrade when I see this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the easiest way I have found to get the correct version installed for your given windows platform is from PowerShell itself.

```
winget install --id Microsoft.Powershell --source winget
```